# Finding Regular Expression Patterns in Pandas Columns

Tags: python, pandas

In a pandas `DataFrame`, I have the following columns:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2], 'coords':['-43.22 -22.15 -43.16 -22.19','-43.32 -22.18 -43.136 -22.149']})
```

The `'coords'` column contains latitude and longitude values. So from the `'coords'` column I need to create two columns, `'latitude'` and `'longitude'`. I thought about doing this using the regular expression `re` library. Latitude values always start with strings `-4` and longitude `-2` and are separated by a blank space. How can I then use a regular expression to create the latitude column that starts with `-4` and ends with white space and the longitude column that starts with `-2` and ends with white space?

Output Example:

```
id |   latitude     | longitude
1  | -43.22, -43.16 | -22.15, -22.19
2  | -43.32, -43.136| -22.18, -22.149
```

Comment: `df1['coords'].str.split(expand=True)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems like it could be more easily done without regex. For instance, if your original `coords` data structure is defined somewhere like:

```
data = ['-43.22 -22.15 -43.16 -22.19', '-43.32 -22.18 -43.136 -22.149']
```

You can split these on white space:

```
data_split = [d.split() for d in data]
# [['-43.22', '-22.15', '-43.16', '-22.19'],
#  ['-43.32', '-22.18', '-43.136', '-22.149']]
```

And then assign values to your coordinates individually:

```
lat = [[d[0], d[2]] for d in data_split]
lon = [[d[1], d[3]] for d in data_split]
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2], 'lat': lat, 'lon': lon})
# id                lat                lon
#  1   [-43.22, -43.16]   [-22.15, -22.19]
#  2  [-43.32, -43.136]  [-22.18, -22.149]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you ask about `regex` solution

```
s_lat = df1.coords.str.extractall(r'(-4\w*\.?\w+)\s*').unstack().agg(', '.join, axis=1)
s_long = df1.coords.str.extractall(r'(-2\w*\.?\w+)\s*').unstack().agg(', '.join, axis=1)

df1[['id']].assign(**{'Latitude': s_lat, 'Longtitude': s_long})

Out[312]:
   id         Latitude       Longtitude
0   1   -43.22, -43.16   -22.15, -22.19
1   2  -43.32, -43.136  -22.18, -22.149
```